# Is there a way to only extract resources with apktool?

Tags: android, apk, apktool

As I only need resources (xml & images) from an Android app (.apk), I would like to save some processing time on using apktool. Is there any parameter that would allow me to disable generation of the smali files and other stuff?

Answer (score -2):

There are several online tools available for this, Try this [link](http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk) and deccompile your apk then you can get your extracted resources along with source code.

Comment: Well, I already have all the files, I actually just need less than what I already get. My question is if there is a parameter for apktool to disable some outputs